# Error with getSymbols - RStudio

Tags: r

I don't know why but I am facing errors when trying to download data from "Oanda" using getSymbols function:

```
library(quantmod)
require(quantmod)

tickers <- c("USD/EUR","EUR/BRL","USD/ARS","USD/BRL","USD/CLP","USD/COP")
tickers2 <- c("USDEUR","EURBRL","USDARS","USDBRL","USDBRL","USDCLP","USDCOP")

getSymbols(tickers, src = "oanda", env = parent.frame(n=1),  
       from = "2014-01-01", to = Sys.Date(), auto.assign = TRUE, 
       warning = FALSE)

Closeprices <- do.call(cbind, lapply(tickers2, function(x) get(x)))
head(Closeprices)

dat1 <- as.data.frame(Closeprices)
dat1$date <- time(Closeprices)

head(dat1)
```

and it returns the following error:

```
> getSymbols("USD/EUR", src = "oanda", env = parent.frame(n=1),  
+            to = Sys.Date(), auto.assign = TRUE, 
+            warning = FALSE)
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

It used to work well, but now it is crashing.

Can you help me out?

Comment: I tested your code adding `verbose = TRUE` to the getSymbols call. It looks like it downloads some data. So maybe the problem is with the website? You may need to sign in to the website first.

Comment: I had the same error when accidentally using a non-existing date such as "2017-06-31". A non-standard quote character could also be a reason for the error...